# Why is Couchbase N1QL Order By slow?

Tags: indexing, sql-order-by, couchbase, sql++

I'm using Couchbase 6.5 Community and try to build an extensive query. But once I add ordering to the query the performance drops a lot (40ms -> 4s).

My index looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX `ndx_get_tracks_3` ON `mybucket`((distinct (array (`t`.`language`) for `t` in `translations` end)),`type`,`published_at` DESC,`is_visible`) WHERE (`type` = "track")
```

And this is the select:

```
SELECT id FROM mybucket
WHERE type = "track" AND is_visible AND ANY t in mybucket.translations SATISFIES (t.`language` IN (["it"])) END
order by published_at DESC
LIMIT 5
```

(I simplified both since it's mainly the order by that's causing problems).

- SELECT execution time: 3.6s
- SELECT execution time without order by: 29.1ms

My first guess was that Couchbase actually does not use the index I'm providing, but the Explain tells me otherwise.

[image: Explain of my select query with order by]

I'm also wondering if N1QL is the right tool or if I should use a View or Fulltext Search instead.

Answer (score 2):

Query use ORDER BY it must produce all possible results and sort the results because last entry might be first in the ORDER BY.

If query ORDER BY follows index keys order it can use index order avoid sort.

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON mybucket(DISTINCT ARRAY t.`language` FOR t IN translations END, is_visible, published_at DESC, id)
WHERE type = "track";

SELECT id FROM mybucket
WHERE type = "track" AND is_visible AND ANY t IN translations SATISFIES t.`language` = "it" END
ORDER BY published_at DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

The following blog explains in details https://blog.couchbase.com/offset-keyset-pagination-n1ql-query-couchbase/

Comment: But my query follows the index keys! And it's still slow.

Comment: Array index key disabling the use of index order https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-40909